# Android, database query selection argument of date

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Say I am accessing SMS database of Android:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
String[] projection = {"_id", "date"};
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

I want to select the rows which have "date" larger than a reference date. I know I need to use selection & selection argument:

```
String selection = "date > ?";

long referenceDateMilli = SOME_VALUE;
//how to define select argument ?
String selectionArgument = ?

Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgument, null);
```

What is the best way to define the argument value of date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates are stored in the SMS table in milliseconds, so you just need to determine that value for a given date and time, and query for any larger. Probably the simplest way to get the date's value is with a `Calendar`. With your given code, the following will return all messages created since the beginning of the year (give or take a second).

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

String[] selectionArgument = { String.valueOf(calendar.getTimeInMillis()) };

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgument, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you sms data, datetime is defined in millis so you can simply take

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
long referenceDateMilli = c.getTimeInMillis();
String[] selectionArgument = {String.valueOf(referenceDateMilli)};
```

**Note: this will work for sms only. for mms it is**

```
long referenceDateMilli = c.getTimeInMillis()%1000;
String[] selectionArgument = {String.valueOf(referenceDateMilli)};
```